# Activate second screen after first screen has closed

Tags: caliburn.micro

I am learning Caliburn.Micro by creating this simple demo app.  I want to display my LoginView first.  Then, after the credentials have been entered and the LoginView has been closed/deactivated, I want to display my UserView. I use the TryClose() method in the LoginViewModel to close the screen. When I run the code below, e.WasClosed is true, the ActivateItem(new UserViewModel()) line is performed, but the LoginView is re-activated.

How do I get the LoginView to completely close/deactivate and the UserView to activate?

Here is the code:

```
class MainViewModel : Conductor<object>.Collection.OneActive
{
    LoginViewModel lvm = new LoginViewModel();

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ActivateItem(lvm);

        lvm.Deactivated += new EventHandler<DeactivationEventArgs>(lvm_Deactivated);
    }

    void lvm_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.WasClosed)
        {
            ActivateItem(new UserViewModel());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st deactive and close the loginview

```
this.DeactivateItem(this.lvm, true);
```

Then activate user view

```
ActivateItem(new UserViewModel());
```

final code

```
this.DeactivateItem(this.lvm, true);
ActivateItem(new UserViewModel());
```